# Modifying SharedPreferences after install (restored through BackupManager)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-backup-service

My app has the ability to backup and restore `SharedPreferences` using an `BackupAgentHelper` class. However there are two entries that must not restored.

Is there a way to reset them after restoring again?

I don't want to put them in a different `SharedPreference`, they have to be in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the onBackup or onRestore methods of the BackupAgent to clear out the values before or after the operation.

Comment: Damn I was thinking too much out of the box and completely forgot about the onRestore interface... Thanks!